# Oracle SQL query partially including the desired results

Tags: sql, oracle

My requirement is to display country name, total number of invoices and their average amount. Moreover, I need to return only those countries where the average invoice amount is greater than the average invoice amount of all invoices.

Query for Oracle Database

```
SELECT cntry.NAME, 
       COUNT(inv.NUMBER), 
       AVG(inv.TOTAL_PRICE)
FROM   COUNTRY cntry JOIN
       CITY ct ON ct.COUNTRY_ID = cntry.ID JOIN
       CUSTOMER cst ON cst.CITY_ID = ct.ID JOIN
       INVOICE inv ON inv.CUSTOMER_ID = cst.ID
GROUP BY cntry.NAME,
         inv.NUMBER,
         inv.TOTAL_PRICE
HAVING AVG(inv.TOTAL_PRICE) > (SELECT AVG(TOTAL_PRICE)
                               FROM INVOICE);
```

*Result*: Austria 1 9500

*Expected*: Austria 2 4825

**Schema**

*Country*

```
ID(INT)(PK) | NAME(VARCHAR)
```

*City*

```
ID(INT)(PK) | NAME(VARCHAR) | POSTAL_CODE(VARCHAR) | COUNTRY_ID(INT)(FK)
```

*Customer*

```
ID(INT)(PK) | NAME(VARCHAR) | CITY_ID(INT)(FK) | ADDRS(VARCHAR) | POC(VARCHAR) | EMAIL(VARCHAR) | IS_ACTV(INT)(0/1)
```

*Invoice*

```
ID(INT)(PK) | NUMBER(VARCHAR) | CUSTOMER_ID(INT)(FK) | USER_ACC_ID(INT) | TOTAL_PRICE(INT)
```

Comment: your group by includes inv.number, while your select has count(inv.number). These are contradictory. Same goes for total_price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no sample data, we can't really tell whether this:

> Expected: Austria 2 4825

is true or not.

---

Anyway: would changing the `GROUP BY` clause to

```
GROUP BY cntry.NAME
```

(i.e. removing additional two columns from it) do any good?

Answer (score 0):

```
`SELECT C.COUNTRY_NAME,COUNT(I.INVOICE_NUMBER),AVG(I.TOTAL_PRICE) AS AVERAGE 
  FROM COUNTRY AS C JOIN CITY AS CS ON C.ID=CS.COUNTRY_ID
 JOIN CUSTOMER AS CUS ON CUS.CITY_ID=CS.ID
 JOIN INVOICE AS I ON I.CUSTOMER_ID=CUS.ID
 GROUP BY C.COUNTRY_NAME,C.ID
 HAVING AVERAGE>(SELECT AVG(TOTAL_PRICE) FROM INVOICE`
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; it would be more helpful if you [edit] your question and include a brief explanation why your answer solves the original question.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

would changing the GROUP BY clause to

```
GROUP BY cntry.NAME , cntry.ID
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Fix your group by columns.
Keep only cntry.name.

It will work.

This is a hackerrank question.